# can't switch view on gluon mobile

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

I am trying to develop an mobile app with gluon mobile (eclipse plugin v2.6.0, MultiViewProject), the content isn't relevant. Mostly according to the gluon documentation I created a first view, which seems to be an login-screen. Everything was fine but when I tried to involve another view called by this login-view it doesn't work.

I used the `switchView` method as I found in the gluon documentation and here at stackoverflow. According to these sources my Code should work but do not. Maybe I made another mistake in the rest of the code?

"Main"-class (except from imports and package declaration):

```
public class GluonApplication extends MobileApplication {
    public static final String START_VIEW = HOME_VIEW; 
    public static final String LOGIN_VIEW = "Login View"; //new home
    public static final String REG_VIEW = "Reg View";

    public General g = new General();

    @Override
    public void init() {
        g.p("init", 2);
        StartView home = new StartView();
        addViewFactory(START_VIEW, () -> home);
        addViewFactory(LOGIN_VIEW, () -> new LoginView());
        addViewFactory(REG_VIEW, () -> new RegView());

        DrawerManager.buildDrawer(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(Scene scene) {
        Swatch.GREY.assignTo(scene);

        scene.getStylesheets().add(GluonApplication.class.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).getIcons().add(new Image(GluonApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon_kT_icon.png")));
    }
```

class `StartView` which includes the login-view:

```
public class StartView extends View {

    public General g = new General();

    public StartView() {
        g.p("set HomeView",2);
        getStylesheets().add(StartView.class.getResource("start.css").toExternalForm());

        LoginSpace lspace = new LoginSpace();
        setCenter(lspace);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> getApplication().getDrawer().open()));
        appBar.setTitleText("Login");
        appBar.setDisable(true);
        appBar.setVisible(false);
    }

    class LoginSpace extends VBox {

        TextField name;
        TextField pass;

        public LoginSpace() {
            g.p("set LoginSpace",2);

            HBox h = new HBox(10.0);
            name = new TextField();
            pass = new TextField();
            Button login = new Button("Anmelden");
            Button reg = new Button("Neu registrieren");

            name.setFloatText("Nutzername");
            pass.setFloatText("Passwort:");
            login.setOnAction(e -> onLogin());
            reg.setOnAction(e -> onReg());

            h.getChildren().addAll(login, reg);
            h.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            getChildren().addAll(name, pass, h);
            KopfrechenTrainer.initKT();

            setSpacing(25);
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            Insets pad = new Insets(20,50,20,50);
            setPadding(pad);
        }

        private void onLogin() {
            g.p("button_login pressed",2);
            String name = this.name.getText();
            String pass = this.pass.getText();
            boolean logIn = KopfrechenTrainer.checkLogin(name, pass);
            if (logIn) ;//HomeView aufrufen, Wenn nicht errormeldung
            else { 
                Alert fault = new Alert(AlertType.NONE, "Nutzername oder Passwort ist nicht korrekt. " + 
                        "Bitte versuche es erneut oder registriere dich neu.");
                fault.showAndWait();
            }

        }

        private void onReg() {
            g.p("button_reg pressed", 2);
            MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView("REG_VIEW");
        }
    }
}
```

If I got that right, the last code line should switch the view to `REG_VIEW` which is also defined in the `GluonApplication` class. The `RegView`-class is build up similar to the class `StartView` so I think it isn't necessary to share too especially because this code is never called while running the program.

Thanks in advance for any help!

btw: `g.p(String, int)` is just for debugging

Comment: The name of your view is `Reg View` where as you are trying to switch to a view with name `REG_VIEW`.

Comment: Oh, I thought I tried out that possibility but unfortunately I did not so far. Now it works as expected, thanks for that help @ItachiUchiha